# RouteCollectionBuilder::setRequirement analog for RoutingConfigurator in Symfony 5.1+

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm updating from Symfony 4 to Symfony 5.4. One of the changes to the Framework Bundle is `RouteCollectionBuilder` being deprecated in favour of `RoutingConfigurator`. But the problem is that I used to set default requirements for the routes like this:

```
$routes->import($confDir . '/{routes}' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
$routes->setRequirement('_locale', 'ru|en|ua|es|fr|pl|de|pt|it|be');
```

But new `RoutingConfigurator` does not have any method which replaces `setRequirement`. How can I define global/default requirements for all routes with the new configurator?

The other thing is that `prefix` argument is also disappeared, so I need to somehow use prefix for the whole route groups (I used to have 3 different route groups with different prefixes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answering after some research.

So, new `RoutingConfigurator::import()` returns an instance of `ImportConfigurator` class, where you can set all default parameters.

So now my code looks like this:

```
$routes
    ->import($confDir . '/{routes}.yaml', 'glob')
    ->prefix('/');

$routes
    ->import($confDir . '/{routing}/*.yaml', 'glob')
    ->prefix('/{_locale}/')
    ->requirements(['_locale' => 'ru|en|ua|es|fr|pl|de|pt|it|be']);

$routes
    ->import($confDir . '/{routing}/' . $this->environment . '/*.yaml', 'glob')
    ->prefix('/');
```